# Sum of elements in a vector between points in an index vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

i have the following problem.

i have in a matrix like this:

> [1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1],
>
> [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]

now want to add up all the values in the 2nd column between the 1s of the first column.
like a distance measurement.

in this case one would expect

> [2 3 2 1 1]

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is the second line always ones(1,n)? How does it affect the expected result?

Comment: You mean the second row right? Not the second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cumulative sum function, then sampling its values on points where A>0. Then just calculating the difference between array elements:

```
A=[1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1];
B=[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
Bsum=cumsum(B);
BsumAtA=Bsum(A>0);
Result=diff(BsumAtA)
```

The 'accumarray' function do it in single command.

Comment: You need to extend `A` and `B` with a one at the end

Answer (score 2):

It would seem you could use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). Since I can't quite understand your array setup since you're talking about rows and columns interchangeably, I put the rows in 2 different variables for simplicity;

```
>>> a=[1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1]      -- Vector of ones for the cutoff points
>>> b=[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]      -- Your sample vector
>>> c=[1 2 1 2 1 1 0 1 1]      -- A slightly more complicated sample vector

>>> accumarray(cumsum(a)',b)
ans =
   2
   3
   2
   1
   1

>>> accumarray(cumsum(a)',c)
ans =
   3
   4
   1
   1
   1
```